# jquery ajax and php wont cooperate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, lamp

i followed [this](http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/) tutorial and also the [official one](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me%3a_Using_Ajax) about jquery using ajax and php and had no luck whatsoever. If I use an xml file instead of a php file for pulling data with jquery everything works splendidly.
(All this on a LAMP server, php works for sure(running joomla with the same configuration))

Comment: "this" isn't a tutorial. What's the problem?

Comment: oops sorry! fixed the link
i have written no code(of my own), i just followed the tutorials

Comment: You got wrong link uder this. Fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard ajax usage

```
$.ajax({
    url : url
    success : function(data) { //do stuff with data here }
})
```

Decide what kind of data you are passing and what is returned from ajax.

Comment: Of course it did! :)  jQuery's documentation page is pretty good with example usage. I understand being new with jQuery is more difficult though.